# How to fix the error for django 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured' with urls?

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

There is an error when i add url to url.py.

when i run the code in terminal : 'python manage.py runserver' ; then the follwing error is displayed in the terminal -

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 
'<module 'polls.urls' from 


'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\website2\\mysite\\polls\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I searched everywhere for the solution but i couldn't find it. Please help me to get out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error might be coming because of the adimn in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

When the polls path was removed by me, the website was running properly. So try comment the polls path in urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

Comment: So I know this is a 2-year-old thread now, but why is this the case? It worked for me, but obviously, I cannot access those routes now.

Answer (score 6):

I think this error most of u misunderstand, circular error imports are very rare in django only in flask it is frequent .

This error is caused by mispelling *'urlpatterns'* in the ***urls.py*** which has been created in a django app.

Also it can be caused by not defining it in your *urlpatterns* in the **urls.py** file

Probably the error is caused by one of the above.

Its that easy

Comment: You answered my issue, John! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

make sure in your `polls` app, you have a file called `urls.py`, which should look something like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.your_view),
]
```

If you haven't configured the `views.py` page in your `polls` app, then you can leave urlpatterns blank for now and you shouldn't see any errors.

Comment: You cant direct to an empty urls.py file. It has to have, at a minimum, what is up on top.