# Django "No Patterns" / Circular Import Error

Tags: python, django

I've scoured all of the issues I can find about this error and tried all of the solutions, yet none (save one; more on that later) worked for me. Every time I start up my app, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'gamerank.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I've checked my files for circular imports, and cannot find any at all.

1. voting/urls.py only imports voting/views.py
2. voting/views.py imports voting/models.py, voting/helpers.py, and voting/forms.py
3. voting/models.py imports from libraries only
4. voting/helpers.py imports from libraries only
5. voting/forms.py imports from voting/models.py (which does not import from voting/forms.py)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362640/13910195) works for me, but I cannot access any of my application after that (because I just commented out the routes), so it's not really a solution in my case.

Here are some of my files:

voting/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'voting'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),

    # auth routes
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register")
]
```

gamerank/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('voting.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Put comma after this.. path("register", views.register, name="register"). Also makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: Added the comma. Tried to makemigrations and was greeted with the same error.

Comment: path('voting', include('voting.urls')),

Comment: I'd rather keep the app at the root route ('/') if possible. Anyways, for the sake of argument, I tried that (both 'voting' and 'voting/') and still no luck.

Comment: Nothing looks out of the ordinary based on what you've shared. This error can arise when using the `reverse()` method if it's called on import (i.e. if it's used outside of a function or class method), because it will import urls.py again (hence a circular import). Worth checking for in voting/views.py.

Comment: As @elyas said, can be caused by using `reverse()` . If that is the case, you can use [reverse_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)

Comment: Please check carefully if you have code outside of a function in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was attempting to run `reverse` in a module that would cause circular import. The solution was to use `reverse_lazy` as suggested in the comments.